# Specflow.Autofac setup for IDisposable dependencies

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, autofac, specflow

I wonder if suggested configuration for `Specflow.Autofac` is "correct" (consistent with one described for build-in `BoDI` DI framework) for dependencies that implement `IDisposable` (like EF Context classes, or EF repositories that depend on EF Context). On the [Context Injection page](https://docs.specflow.org/projects/specflow/en/latest/Bindings/Context-Injection.html) documentation states: "If the injected objects implement `IDisposable`, they will be disposed after the scenario is executed."

I don't think the recommended setup described on [Specflow.Autofac](https://docs.specflow.org/projects/specflow/en/latest/Integrations/Autofac.html) page has the same behavior:

```
builder.RegisterTypes(typeof(TestDependencies).
    Assembly.GetTypes().
    Where(t => Attribute.IsDefined(t, typeof(BindingAttribute))).
    ToArray()).
    # The following constrain
    SingleInstance();
```

Because according to the inline `Autofac` documentation for `SingleInstance()`: "Configure the component so that every dependent component or call to `Resolve()` gets the same, shared instance" [[3](https://autofac.org/apidoc/html/49B17EDB.htm)]. Which means that each of the step classes will be singletons and will be keeping their dependencies until all the tests finish executing, so `IDisposable` dependencies will not be disposed and recreated.

Am I correct in my understanding? And should I omit `SingleInstance()` from the step registration if they are using (directly or indirectly) `IDisposable` classes and have a separate Test data context class (separate from `ScenarioContext` class that Specflow provides)? And what is the recommended way of registering `IDisposable` and EF Context components for Specflow acceptance scenarios?

Comment: Have you tried omitting the call to `SingleInstance()` and see how your tests behave?

Comment: I did, it recreates a class containing a step method for each call.

Comment: This all depends on the scope of the DI container. I know with the default BoDi container, SpecFlow creates one set of objects per scenario. I'm not very familiar with Autofac. I've used it a little bit. I'm pretty sure step definition classes, and their dependencies, are initialized at the beginning of a scenario and then disposed of at the end. You don't get a "singleton" for the entire test run. It is a "singleton"/single instance for a *single scenario* and each scenario gets its own, fresh, DI container. If your tests work, then keep `SingleInstance()`. Is there an error?

Comment: @GregBurghardt, it looks like it works exactly the same way with Autofac. Before each scenario new container is created. I was confused about how to handle disposable classes, like DB Context, because it is recommended to dispose them right after operation is performed. I think what might be a right thing to do is to create a wrapper for `IDisposable` dependencies with the same interface and make steps consume it instead of such dependencies directly. Thank you!

Comment: No need to create a wrapper for those dependencies. For something like the DB context, I usually initialize it at the beginning of a step definition inside a `using(...) { ... }` block. That way the DB context gets disposed of before the end of the step. It also prevents false failures or false passes due to the many layers of Entity Framework (or NHibernate) caching.